# Angular Material can't set hasErrors(always empty) on

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unxe7d?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts

I'm trying to set hasErrors on formControl which I use in matFormField.
Like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-error-state-matcher-example',
  template: `<form class="example-form">
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput
                      placeholder="Email" 
                      [formControl]="emailFormControl">
              </mat-form-field>
    {{emailFormControl.hasError('incorrect')}} 
  {{emailFormControl.valid}} 
</form>`,
  styleUrls: ['./input-error-state-matcher-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorStateMatcherExample implements OnInit {
  emailFormControl = new FormControl('');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.emailFormControl.setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
  }
}
```

But emailFormControl.hasError('incorrect') always false and emailFormControl.valid is true. Is this wrong behavior or I doing something wrong?

Comment: Having the code of your stackblitz would be better than having the demonstration only.

Comment: @trichetriche i fixed link

Comment: great, but I already provided you a working answer if you care to look at it

Comment: And please, mark your issue as resolved. We helped you, the least you can do is notify future users looking for answers that you actually resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit`.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.emailFormControl.setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
  }
```

Comment: why should that make a difference?

Comment: Because on init doesn't wait for the view to be loaded. If you set an error on the form before it being loaded, it won't work. Try on his stackblitz if you don't believe me.

Comment: Its not about me believing in your answer or not, not even if it works or not. Just take the time to explain why this works and the previous approach doesnt.

Comment: I agree I should explain it, even though this is the basics of Angular. Sorry for not getting what you meant.